# Adding a cocos2d view to a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

I have integrated cocos2d 2.0 into an existing iOS project and would like to be able to create a view and add it to an existing view as a subview.

Where should the cocos2d setup code be placed and how is the cocos2d view then made visible inside the UIView?

I have followed [Ray Wenderlichs tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit) and it doesn't help with the specific issue. A lot of the code is deprecated as well.

Is it possible to do the cocos2d setup inside the cocos2d class I create? Im not sure on how to connect the `CCDirector` and `glView` to the current architecture.

If I do the setup in the `AppDelegate`, what exactly is needed in the cocos2d view (`CCLayer` e.g.) and how is it made visible? The template uses a navigation controller, but I do not use that.

How is the cocos2d view linked to the setup, and who takes care of displaying the view?

Comment: Did you had any luck with this? If so, I would really appreciate if you could share your findings, I'm having the same problem here! Thanks