# Add Cocos2D view in UIView

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, spine

As the title said, I am having a problem adding cocos2d scene into UIView layer. I want to use `spine-cocos2d-objc` in my existing project, but i face some issues.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938417/adding-a-cocos2d-view-to-a-uiview) but unfortunately, no answer.

`spine-cocos2d-objc` is successfully integrated in my existing project, but i have no clue how to create a scene inside some of my view controller.

In the [example](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/3.7/spine-cocos2d-objc), it launch full screen of cocos2d scene in `AppDelegate`

```
[self setupCocos2dWithOptions:@{
        CCSetupDepthFormat: @GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
        CCSetupTabletScale2X: @YES,
        CCSetupScreenMode: CCScreenModeFixed,
        CCSetupScreenOrientation: CCScreenOrientationPortrait,
        CCSetupShowDebugStats: @YES,
    }];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[SpineboyExample scene]];
```

But in my project, i just need to launch cocos2d in some view controller. 
Notes: I know that cocos2d is such an old framework. But I think, this is the only option I had.

SpriteKit, actually much easier than cocos2D in terms of integrating with UIKit, but sadly, Spine runtime that using SpriteKit has no support for newest Spine features.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is by far the closest solution i have tried. I tried to embed CCScene from Cocos2D into my UIView using this

```
- (void)setupCocos2D {
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[self view] frame]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];
    glView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:0];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setView:glView];
    CCScene *scene = [GoblinsExample scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
}
```

Right now, I can see `CCDirectorDisplayLink` in my view layer. But unfortunately, all that i got is only white page. The scene is successfully load all assets that needed, but still it does not appear in my `UIView`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does spine do that requires cocos2d? I wonder if there is something else that you can use that supports SpriteKit?

Comment: @Fogmeister i just made an edit. Some progress were made, but still I can't see the asset loaded.